# Не получается передать id в retrofit'е

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Хочу передать Id в retrofit'e 1.9, но возникает следующая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код метода:

```
private void uploadVideo() {
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/")
            .build();

    API apiInterface = adapter.create(API.class);

    Callback<VideoUpload> v = apiInterface.uploadVideo(new Callback<VideoUpload>() {

        @Override
        public void success(VideoUpload videoUpload, Response response) {
            String id = videoUpload.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Код интерфейса:

```
    @GET("/video/{id}")
void uploadVideo(@Path("id") String id, Callback<VideoUpload> callback);
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что метод объявлен с двумя параметрами, а вызвать Вы пытаетесь его с одним?

Answer (score 4):

У вас не хватает одного параметра в вызове метода. Вы объявили метод, как

```
void uploadVideo(@Path("id") String id, Callback<VideoUpload> callback);
```

А вызывать пытаетесь, как

```
uploadVideo(new Callback<VideoUpload>());
```

Не передаете `String id`, а только `Callback<VideoUpload> callback`

Comment: Точно, спасибо) не скажете почему он предлагает между String id поставить "," или ")" ?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, не подскажу, потому, что непонятно, что у вас за  String id,)

Comment: @VadimMorozov, покажите конкретно код, который у вас вызывает вопрос, хотя бы строчку

Comment: студия предложила мне изменить @GET("/video/{id}")
    void uploadVideo(@Path("id") String id, Callback<VideoUpload> callback); на это @GET("/video/{id}")
    Callback<VideoUpload> uploadVideo(@Path("id") String id, Callback<VideoUpload> callback);
ошибка пропала. Но я прописал значение id просто, без типа String Callback<VideoUpload> v = apiInterface.uploadVideo(id, new Callback<VideoUpload>() {
еще не знаю на сколько это будет верным)

Comment: @VadimMorozov, все равно непонятно.